# why is the file saving here?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

When I take a photo with my app I would like to save it like this

```
Android/data/com.androidproject/files/Camera/photo.png
```

However it is currently saving here, according to my Log.v statement

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.androidproject/files/Camera/photo.png
```

This is my code

```
private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File dir = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("Camera"),
                    "photo.png");               
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(dir);
            Log.v("FILE", "" + outputFileUri);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CALL_BACK);
        }

    }
```

So, why isn't the file saving to the desired location? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getFilesDir()` instead of `getExternalFilesDir()` to save them to the internal memory.

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "Camera" + File.separator + "photo.png");
f.mkdirs();
```

This will setup your new file, and make sure the path to it exists.

Comment: When i switch that it will no longer take the argument "Camera". Where would I declare that as my folder? Also, I have a seperate fragment that uses that exact command, getExternalFilesDir() and it works perfectly

Comment: The command `getExternalFiesDir()` will always get your apps specific file storage location on the SDCARD of your device.

Comment: the weirdest thing... if I change it to `getActivity().getFilesDir()` I cant save the photo. As in the camera takes the photo, then when I try and press the checkmark to finish the operation nothing happens...

Comment: guess ill just make another question